# How to get the access token from azure using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-functions, access-token

We just wanted to get the access token of azure using asp.net MVC web application.

We have to use the below line of code to get the azure access token.

```
 Dim authorityUri As String = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize"

 Dim authContext As AuthenticationContext = New AuthenticationContext(authorityUri)

 Dim TokenTask = Await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, ClientCredetial)

 Dim getToken = TokenTask.AccessToken()
 Return getToken
```

But we are getting a response to the open azure login page. Can you please help me with this.

Is there any way to get token from azure using asp.net MVC So please suggest Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not that simple, [there are a number of authentication flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows), which one do you need to use? And, why is this tagged with c# ?

Comment: Can you format the code so that it is little bit more readable? Yes Authorization flow shows login page coz it does not issue token without user being logged in. You need to use client_credentials grant type. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: Now it's good to readable. Can you please help me to directly get an access token using asp/net MVC or is this any other way to get token. Please suggest.

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to implement the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

The authority is incorrect. It should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}`.

Not sure why you add the C# tag but your code is VB.

So here is a C# sample for your reference.

```
 string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
 string clientId = "{clientId}";
 string secret = "{secret}";
 string resource = "{resource}";

 var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

 var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential).Result.AccessToken;
```